# How can i use Faker.js to generate random data for protractor test cases.?

Tags: angularjs, protractor, faker

I would like to generate random input for protractor using faker.js. Please provide a way for using faker.js with protractor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be simple. Just generate random data in Conf.js and refer them in your tests

```
onPrepare: function() {
    var Faker = require('./Faker');
    browser.params.randomName = Faker.Name.findName(); // Rowan Nikolaus
    browser.params.randomEmail = Faker.Internet.email(); // Kassandra.Haley@erich.biz
},
```

And in your tests just use these dynamically generated data

```
element(By.css('.blahblah')).sendKeys(browser.params.randomName)
```

For more details refer my blog @ [Using FakerJs in Protractor](https://testautomation-aditya.com/2016/09/05/generate-huge-data-setsrandom-data-in-protractor-tests-using-fakerjs/)